# making arrays from tab-delimited text file column

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, csv

I was wondering if anyone could help a desperate newbie with perl with the following question. I've been trying all day but with my perl book at work, I can't seem to anything relevant in google...or maybe am genuinely stupid with this.

I have a file that looks something like the following:

```
Bob     April
Bob     April
Bob     March
Mary    August
Robin   December
Robin   April
```

The output file I'm after is:

```
Bob     April April March
Mary    August
Robin   December April
```

So that it lists each month in the order that it appears for each person.

I tried making it into a hash but of course it wouldn't let me have duplicates so I thought I would like to have arrays for each name (in this example, Bob, Mary and Robin).
I'm afraid to upload the code I've been trying to tweak because I know it'll be horribly wrong. I think I need to define(?) the array. Would this be correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I promise I will be studying more about perl in the meantime.

Thank you for your time, patience and help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (defined $old_name) {
        $name=$1;
        $month=$2;
        if ($name eq $old_name) { 
            $array{$month}++;   
            }
        else { 
            print "$old_name";
            foreach (@array)  { 
                push (@array, $month);
                print "\t@array";
                }
            print "\n";
            @array=(); 
            $array{$month}++; 
            }
        }
    else { 
        $name=$1;
        $month=$2;
        $array{month}++;
        }
    $old_name=$name; 
    }
print "$old_name"; 
foreach (@array)  {
    push (@array, $month);
    print "\t@array";
    }
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks overly complicated for such a simple task.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($name, $mon) = split;
    push @{$hash{$name}}, $mon;
}

for my $name (keys %hash) {
    my @months = @{$hash{$name}};
    print "$name\t@months\n";
}    
__DATA__
Bob     April
Bob     April
Bob     March
Mary    August
Robin   December
Robin   April
```

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhat close. You do want to use a hash with names being the key, but as you can see, for each name you want to store an **array** of months, so the data structure you are looking to use is a hash of arrays (or rather array references, as this is implemented in Perl)

While at it, please don't get into the habit of using global variables - 100% of your code should have "`use strict; use warnings;`" at the beginning, and locally scoped (`my`) variables.

```
use strict;
my %data;
my @sorted_names; # Only needed if you care which order to print the results
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $month) = split(/s+/);
    if (! $data{$name}) {
        # Initialize to empty array reference if first time. 
        # Not required - perl will do it for you
        $data{$name} ||= []; 
        # Only needed if you want to print results in the same order of names as input.
        push @sorted_names, $name;
    }
    push @{ $data{$name} }, $month;
}

foreach my $name (@sorted_names) {
    print "$name\t" . join(" ", @{ $data{$name} }) . "\n";
}
# If don't care about name order, just do "foreach my $name (keys %data) {"
```

Comment: You do not need to initialize a scalar value into an (empty) array ref, it is done automatically.

Comment: @TLP - true, but it's a bit of an unintuitive magic to a total newbie.

Answer (score 1):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %content;
open my $fh, '<file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  push @{$content{$1}}, $2 if /^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/;
}
close $fh;
foreach (keys %content) {
  print $_, "\t";
  foreach my $item (@{$content{$_}}) {
    print "$item ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %content;
open my $fh, '<file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  push @{$content{$1}}, $2 if /^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/;
}
close $fh;
print "$_\t@{$content{$_}}\n" for keys %content;
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %content;
open my $fh, '<file.txt' or die $!;
s/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/{push @{$content{$1}}, $2}/e for <$fh>;
close $fh;
print "$_\t@{$content{$_}}\n" for keys %content;
```

***Output:***

```
Bob     April April March 
Mary    August 
Robin   December April
```

for file `file.txt` with content:

```
Bob     April
Bob     April
Bob     March
Mary    August
Robin   December
Robin   April
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do this is using perl's  push and pop functions.(since you are getting started with perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html , http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html )
you should keep a global array for each name(eg @bobmonths) and push a month each time you find one.
When done, print out the name and the array:

```
while(<>)
{
chomp;
push(@bobmonths, $2)

...
}
print @bobmonths
```